# Best place to handle API exceptions in Vuex (in the actions or in the component)

Tags: rest, vue.js, error-handling, vuex

Lets say I've got a Vue (+Vuex) project, while API calls are made inside actions only.
And lets say I invoke an action that emits one of those API calls.

Where would be the best place to handle the exception returned from the API call? Does it make sense to let it propagate up to the component and not to catch it inside the action?

So far, I'm  handling the exception inside the actions. But in case I want to react to each failure case differently INSIDE THE COMPONENT (like marking a textbox in red if the response's status code was 404, but do something else in case the response status code was 500), I would want to throw it back to the component and leave the decision of what to do with it to be determined there and not in the action.

It seems weird to let components know and manage the different status codes that an API can return (`if (response.error.status === 404) {...}`), but they still have to know what type of error was returned.

**First option** I could think of was to wrap the relevant errors with different custom errors (create a class for each type of error caught inside the action, throw the wrapped object back to the component, blah blah). Not perfect since I catch the exceptions in two different layers and need to create a different error class for each possible error.

**Second option** was not to catch it in the action, and leave it to be caught in the component.
Not that good since I want to hide the logical part of the API from the component, that shouldn't know the structure of the response.

**Third option** was to add a new property in the store to tag failures in this api call and to listen on it in the component, but this approach seems like an overkill for the store.

I just wanted to ensure there isn't anything I'm missing, since my dilemma sounds like something that might be relevant for almost any project. Any better ideas of an architecture I may use?

Comment: all comes down to preference and your use case. if you want global error handling and re-use funtionality to push toast like notifications, you should probably catch in the action and trigger another state change to display the error. If your errors should be displayed directly in the component, you should just return the promise and handle it there. I would go with the first approach, since it has much higher re-usability. But especially when working with forms, you might want errors be displayed next to the according fields.

Comment: The right thing to do in my use-case is to handle it within the component, as I would like to display the error in the form-field under the "wrong" field input. But it sounds like a bad practice to let the component handle the error object came from the API call, and to know the request object structure, that's why I thought about mapping it in the action-layer, but this method has it's downsides as well.

Comment: I'm facing a very similar crossroad in my code structure. What did you end up choosing and are you still glad you choose it?